# Particular solution to $Ax=b$ vs $b$ itself

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry, I don't know how to title very well.

I just started Linear Algebra 1, and have gotten to learn particular and general solutions to system of equations.

I was faced with an example and noticed that the particular solution was not equal to $b$.

So I was wondering, is the particular solution different to $b$ in a system of equations, $Ax=b$?

I feel like I don't really understand the concept of what it means to be "a solution to a system of equations".

Comment: You are looking for vectors to multiply by a matrix that will give you the vector $b.$ If $A$ is the identity matrix, $b$ is a solution to your equation, and the only one. Generally a not completely analogous situation to consider is the equation $ax=b,$ where $a$ and $b$ are, say, integers. You don't expect $x=b$ to be a solution except in very special circumstances.

Comment: Would you expect $x$ to equal $5$ in the equation $2x=5$?

Answer (score 0):

A solution of a system of $m$ equations in the $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a finite sequence $(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ such that when you make the substitutions $x_1 = a_1,\dots, x_n=a_n$ all the equations are simultaneously true.

You can note that the system can be written as an single equation involving a matrix $A$ of the coefficients, a column matrix (also called an vector) $b$ and a vector $x$ where the variables are the inputs, using matrix multiplication.

So a solution can be seen as an vector $a = [a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n]^t$ (I'm writing the vector here as an row matrix and taking the transpose to make it an column matrix) that makes the equation $Ax = b$ be true when you make $x = a$.

Given this, a particular solution is just any solution of the system $Ax = b$. A general solution is any solution of the form $a + h$, where $a$ is a particular solution and $h$ is a solution for the system $Ax = 0$ the so called homogeneous system associated to the original system.